# Addon.d bash script for removing apks after nightly reflash on Android 5.1 CM12.1 not working

Tags: android, bash

I'm trying to have a bash script in /system/addon.d/ that removes unwanted apks from a nightly Android 5.1 (CM12.1) install for my Galaxy Nexus phone. Each new nightly reflash will reinstall some system apps so that is why I want a script to reverse this action so I do not have to do it manually.

There are some backup scripts that run fine (SU, GApps) but my own script does not work. It can be found below.

I placed the script in /system/addon.d/ with permissions -rwxr-xr-x (same permissions set as other scripts in addon.d). When flashing I do not see the echo and the apps are not removed.

I have tried google and researched other scripts but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Help is appreciated!

```
#!/sbin/sh
#
# /system/addon.d/80-autoclean.sh
#

. /tmp/backuptool.functions

list_files() {
cat <<EOF
AudioFX
BackupRestoreConfirmation
BasicDreams
Browser
CMAccount
CMBugReport
Calendar
CyanogenSetupWizard
DeskClock
Eleven
Email
Exchange2
Galaxy4
HTMLViewer
HoloSpiralWallpaper
LatinIME
LiveWallpapers
LiveWallpapersPicker
LockClock
NoiseField
PhaseBeam
PhotoPhase
PhotoTable
Tag
Terminal
ThemeChooser
ThemesProvider
UserDictionaryProvider
VisualizationWallpapers
VpnDialogs
EOF
}

case "$1" in
  backup)
    # Stub
  ;;
  restore)
    # Stub
  ;;
  pre-backup)
    # Stub
  ;;
  post-backup)
    # Stub
  ;;
  pre-restore)
    # Stub
  ;;
  post-restore)
    list_files | while read FILE; do
        rm -rf /system/app/$FILE.apk
        rm -rf /system/priv-app/$FILE.apk
        rm -rf /system/app/$FILE
        rm -rf /system/priv-app/$FILE
        echo "Removed $FILE"
    done
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in [Super User](http://superuser.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I disagree. Super User is not meant for smartphones and I consider the bash file to be programming.